# PyCharm diff modal during commit show "reversed" diff

Tags: git, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

When I make changes to the code in PyCharm and want to use the git > commit option to commit my changes, I usually use the diff tool to have a GUI display of what changed.

I can then select or un-select the changes I want to commit either to commit/not commit them or to separate changes into several coherent commits.

Let's say I deleted an unused import and then created a method, the thing is when I show the diff, the visual tool compares the files in "reverse". Which means that the changes I can select or not are:

- **addition** of new imports (unused)
- **deletion** of a method

I'm not sure why PyCharm would compare files like this since it's clearly stated "your version" vs. "origin commit hash".

This means I need to un-select *all* changes if I want my new code to be committed.

Is there a way to tell PyCharm to present things the other way around?